# VueJs 3 & Docker & Windows - Webpack watchOptions doesn't seem to work

Tags: windows, docker, webpack, vue.js

I'm using the latest VueJS with the vue-cli-service in a dockerized dev environment. Everything works great, except for vuejs / webpack being notified when files change. (Due to there not being any inotify.) It works exactly as it should on OSX.

I researched and found about the configureWebpack option for the vue.js.config and turned polling on, but no luck - still doesn't work under Windows.

Here are my docker-compose.yml, my Dockerfile for the vuejs image, and the vue.config.js. Anyone else have this setup working under windows that might see what I'm doing wrong?

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.8.0-alpine

# Install Vue Cli via node
RUN npm install -g @vue/cli @vue/cli-service-global

RUN mkdir /src
WORKDIR /src
COPY ./src/package* /src/
RUN npm install
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: './web'
    volumes: 
      - /src/node_modules
      - ./web/src:/src      
    working_dir: /src
    ports:
      - "4000:8080"
    command: npm run serve
    # stdin_open: true
    # tty: true

  api:
    build: './api'
    volumes:
      - ./api/src:/src
    working_dir: /src
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: rails s
    depends_on:
      - data
    # stdin_open: true
    # tty: true

  data:
    build: './data'
    volumes:
      - data-postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

volumes:
  data-postgresql:
    external: true
```

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    watchOptions: {
      ignored: /node_modules/,
      poll: 1000
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved. Finally. Thanks to a random example of a webpack config somewhere.

The vue.config.js watchoptions needs to be one more level down under "devServer". This seems to work:

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devServer: {
      watchOptions: {
        ignored: /node_modules/,
        poll: 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this error: **ValidationError: Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
         - options has an unknown property 'watchOptions'. These properties are valid:
           object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, setupMiddlewares?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }**

Comment: Me too. Using Vue3 with this as vue.config.js: `const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
})`

Comment: me 2. seems the watchIgnorePlugin is deprecated and can no longer be used (not possible to install with vue3)... and seems watchOptions is NOT allowed both inside devServer and outside devServer... Seems the devs of vue/cli somehow fumbled and forgot to allow this :(